# Insert several columns and rows on a matrix based on their finale indices

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, insert, nan

I don't think I found a post solving this specific issue. Here is the setting:

`A_i` is the initiale matrix of size n x m, and I would like to add `NaN` value such that the resulting matrix `A_f` has these NaN values at the row and column indices stored in a previously vector `b`.

For simple purpose, let's simplify the problem to a 1D A vector of small size. For instance:

```
A_i = [3 4 12 20 3];
b = [1 3 6 7 10];
```

Resulting matrix will would like:

```
A_f = [NaN 3 NaN 4 12 NaN NaN 20 3 NaN];
```

Such that

```
>> A_f(b)
ans =
    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

I'm looking for the most clean solution, not just a iterative workaround...

Answer (score 0):

Here's my best solution:

```
>> A_f = zeros(1,numel(A_i)+numel(b));
>> A_f(b) = NaN;
>> A_f(~isnan(A_f)) = A_i

A_f =

   NaN   3   NaN     4    12   NaN   NaN    20     3   NaN
```

Who can find better ? (less lines, avoid using a new `Af` matrix but directly on `Ai`...)

For a 2D `A` matrix

```
>> A_i = [3 4 12 ; 20 3 6];
>> b1 = [2]; 
>> b2 = [1 4]; 
>> 
>> A_f = zeros(size(A_i)+[numel(b1) numel(b2)]);
>> A_f(b1,:) = NaN;
>> A_f(:,b2) = NaN;
>> A_f(~isnan(A_f)) = A_i

A_f =

   NaN     3     4   NaN    12
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN    20     3   NaN     6
```